# Is there a way to combine 2 "FileSystem.CopyDirectory" statements so I get only one progress window?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Is there a way to combine 2 "FileSystem.CopyDirectory" statements so I get only one progress window? I'm using the below 2 statements in my C# application. It works fine, but It give 2 progress windows one after the other for each statement. Is there a way to have only one progress bar windows that handle both statements... And therefore calculates the time for both as well?

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(@"C:\test\HP1", @"c:\test\HP3", UIOption.AllDialogs);
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(@"C:\test\HP2", @"c:\test\HP4", UIOption.AllDialogs);
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: No they are two separate operations. You wouldn't be able to do this in file Explorer either so it doesn't make logical sense to the user. What happens if an error happens during the second copy do you roll back the first copy?

Comment: @MattWilko Actually this makes sense. The [`IFileOperation` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx) is designed so multiple operations can be performed at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't with the built-in methods. The .Net wrapper of `SHFileOperation` only deals with one object at the same time.

You could use the COM `IFileOperation` interface, but you'll have to build your own .Net wrappers. If you're interested, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx) could help.

Comment: Nice insight to what's going on under the covers.